# The 'No True Scotsman' Fallacy and Judaism

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, heterodox, orthodox

I don't know if this has been asked before, perhaps with different terminology.

There is a well-known fallacy, that in the realm of religious debates, comes up often especially with regards to "The One True Way of [insert religion]"™, and that is the No True Scotsman Fallacy, which was explained simply thus:

> Person A: "No Scotsman puts sugar on his porridge."
> Person B: "But my uncle Angus is a Scotsman and he puts sugar on his porridge."
> Person A: "But no **true** Scotsman puts sugar on his porridge." (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman))

In other words, appealing to a higher or greater truth is not a way to dispute other views that rise from within the same group being discussed or debated, because what right do you have to claim the truth for yourself? (I hope I defined it properly).

With regards to Judaism, there are several different sects and denominations, and within these there are sub-groups as well, all with differing views on halacha, kabbalah, interpreting the Torah, hashkafah, and so forth. It's not uncommon that when speaking to a non-Jewish party about your Jewish beliefs that they'll ask: "Well, so and so, who's from a different Jewish group, believes X, while you believe Y. How do you know that you're right and he's wrong?" In such a case, answering: "So and so doesn't believe in **True** Judaism™" doesn't work, because who are you to say what "True Judaism" is?

Therefore, I was wondering whether within Orthodoxy there is a way around this fallacy, or should we simply say: Have emunah, wait for the Mashiach (or work to bring him) and in the end the world will know the truth? True, in some cases it's possible to simply point out internal contradictions within other groups, but the same case can be made against Orthodoxy, as well as considering that this doesn't work 100% of the time.

Comment: Judaism has no official stance on basically anything, so there is no "true Judaism". Judaism is what the Jew makes it

Comment: Would the Rambam's 13 Ikkarim act as a guide for "True Judaism" at least in the mind of those who follow him?

Comment: @ezra note I am talking about Orthodox Judaism in general, with regards to non-Orthodox groups, such as Reform, Conservative, Karaites, Reconstructionist, and so forth. I think there are things that are agreed by at least the vast majority of OJs that are red lines that once crossed, you have either reached another group or are in a whole different religion.

Comment: @rosends I think it could, but the counter argument would be: Well, who says the Rambam is correct (after all, there are other lists of Ikarim)?

Comment: Wait and see if their great-grandchildren identify as Jews and attend synagogue. That one works pretty well. Rabbi Emanuel Feldman shlit'a suggests that homiletically as an explanation for the Gemara's  "Elders of the Academy of Athens" riddle about "the placenta of a mule." You can hybridize all kinds of things with Judaism, but the ones that don't belong don't last for more than one generation.

Comment: @Shalom Reform has been around for over 150 years. I am sure that there are people today who identify as Jewish and go to synagogue and trace themselves to RJs from a century ago, if not more. Per your suggestion, does this mean Reform has a place in Judaism?

Comment: I think you're missing the problem with using this kind of argument. The fallacy is only relevant if you care about the term "Scotsman" for some other purpose (meaning for some reason it's relevant to know who is and isn't officially a Scotsman). I don't care if you define "Judaism" to include Christianity, just if you do so know that that's #NotMyReligion. I know what my religion is no matter what you call it. The whole thing is a word game; everyone agrees it's not fallacious to define whatever groups you want.

Comment: I’m not sureI quite get what you are asking. Is your question simply how to justify something that you can’t prove to be true?

Comment: @Harel13 of the people who go to a Reform Temple on a weekly basis today, I would venture that over half of them had an Orthodox great-grandparent.

Comment: Some classic responses: a) אלו ואלו דברי אלהים חיים. b) there are 12 gates of heaven corresponding to the tribes, through which the service of diverse communities/sects ascends (Lurianic), c) yes, group X deviates from classical Jewish sources in the following xyz ways, nevertheless they uphold universally agreed upon foundational beliefs (so they are still true Scotsmen.. errr I mean true practitioners of Judaism)... @Harel13 are these the types of answers you are looking for?

Comment: @DoubleAA while a very nice thought, I don't know if that holds any water in a debate or any attempt to explain why Orthodoxy is the correct way to observe Judaism.

Comment: @Harel13 Of course not! And there's no reason to expect that asserting a specific person's religious practices would have any value there. It's just about your ability to define the boundaries of a belief system. (NTScotscman is relevant to fighting over labels of categories, not categories themselves.) Whether anyone cares about your definition is another question.

Comment: @Deuteronomy no, perhaps I wasn't clear enough. I am not asking how to explain contradictions within Orthodoxy. B"H I am aware of the different answers you have brought. I am asking about responding when queried about Orthodoxy versus forms of Judaism that are generally viewed as illegitimate by Orthodoxy, such as Reform or Karaism.

Comment: @Harel13 thanks for the clarification. Personally I would point to whether there was a tremendous rupture in continuity of belief/practice. While it is certainly the case that 21st c. Orthodoxy today looks different than 9th c. Geonic Judaism and again different than 1st c. BCE and so on... but if you take these spans of time and reduce them to decades and/or half centuries, you will not be able to pinpoint a moment and say "ahah! here's where it went off the rails and turned radically into something else!" Whereas the other denominations consciously and deliberately broke with the past.

Comment: related https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/107938/1144

Answer (score 2):

Orthodox Judaism and being a true Scotsman aren’t analogous. The latter is a cultural situation that no one can really determine. There are  no “Scotsman principles” that all Scotsman claim to follow.

Conversely Orthodox Judaism  does have   boundaries that can not be crossed to be considered a member of the group. Someone who says they do not believe that the Torah was given on Har Sinai or that there was a binding  oral Torah  given with it can not claim to be an Orthodox Jew according to any definition of Orthodox Judaism accepted by any group that calls itself  Orthodox. Anyone claiming to say something that denies those beliefs can be told "this is something an Orthodox Jew would say" Even if the person/rabbi/group saying it claims to be Orthodox. Those are more broad examples you can narrow it down further.

In the secular world this is a common concept as well. I’m reading these days   that  Trumps  lawyers (a law professor himself) trying  to advance a legal argument to Trump even after being told by fellow lawyers “You can argue that in a law school classroom but no judge would accept it” borders on the crime of the century . Along with plenty of other sanctions and possible disbarment for other lawyers of his who didn't break any laws but are accused of advancing lawsuits when they "had no reasonable basis to believe the lawsuits filed were not frivolous". Is that the Scotsmans fallacy or l'havdil like saying "there is no basis in Halacha to say such a thing" , "you can't rely on Rabbi X because he says things that have no basis in halacha" etc.?

Comment: I’m not sure I see the difference. Surely there are some people that everyone would agree are not Scottsmen, and surely there are some people that everyone would agree are Scottsmen. The uncertainty is only where the line is drawn. This is much the same as with Orthodoxy. There will be some people that everyone agrees are Orthodox, some people that everyone agrees are not Orthodox, and some people in between.

Comment: The difference is there is no actual  rules for being a Scotsmen. There are rules in Orthodox Judaism .  Where the line is drawn would depend on the question but there is an ability to draw that line based on principles of Orthodox Judaism and disqualify those who pass it.  By a Scotsman due to absence of a Scotsman authority   those lines can not be determined by anyone. If  someone is on the border  being  questioned  if he  is a Scotsman or not the opinions both way would  boil down to "because I said so"

Comment: What would it boil down to if someone on the border is questioned if he is Orthodox?

Comment: If he can make a valid  argument to vouch for his Orthodoxy based on Orthodox Jewish law.  The ones to decide it's validity would need the expertise in Orthodox Jewish law to do so. If someone is sincerely trying to meet that criteria they  would be able to determine it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a totally different question from the "no true Scotsman" fallacy. That fallacy is a way for members of a group to disassociate themselves from other members of a group who claim to be acting on the group's behalf. For example, when religious extremists (of any religion) perform violence in the name of their religion, it's a fallacy for other members of the religion to say, "Those people aren't real members of my religion." Traditional Judaism in particular is very unlikely to fall into this fallacy because we tend to believe that there are objective, measurable, and well-known criteria for being considered Jewish.

The scenario you're describing is totally different. Here, there are two people making conflicting assertions about what "Judaism" believes. The real answer to "How do you know that you're right and he's wrong?" is simply, "This is what *I* believe". Who is correct and who is wrong is unverifiable.

Comment: You seem to be differentiating between disassociating from certain people and disassociating from certain ideas or beliefs. I don't understand why the latter is different from the NTSman fallacy. In the end, the disassociation from people is due to them having beliefs that are different from yours and you find those to be illegitimate. I don't see how the traditional Jewish criteria for Jewishness is relevant here.

Comment: @Harel13 because the "No True Scotsman" fallacy is entirely about identity. That's just what it is. It's not a logical fallacy to say "Reform Judaism is wrong;" it's an opinion.

Comment: The first two sentences of the Wikipedia page concisely define NTS: "No true Scotsman, or appeal to purity, is an informal fallacy in which one attempts to protect their universal generalization from a falsifying counterexample by excluding the counterexample improperly.[1][2][3] Rather than abandoning the falsified universal generalization or providing evidence that would disqualify the falsifying counterexample, a slightly modified generalization is constructed ad-hoc to definitionally exclude the undesirable specific case and counterexamples like it by appeal to rhetoric."

Comment: The "No true Scotsman" fallacy has less to do with porridge these days than belonging to the SNP (which I call the Scottish Nationalistic Party).  For what it's worth, I put cinnamon and honey into my porridge - and I am a true Scotswoman who belongs to a clan that goes back a long, long, long, long way.  I've even got the tartan to prove it!